# Smell Trail Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have mouse and cats moving across the view, and I'd like to be able to make a smell trail to the mouses. The smell should fade away with time, simulating the intensity of the smell. If a cat enter on the smell trail, the cat must follow the smell trail to kill the mouse.

I will leave a part of my code, in case it helps:

```
...
mice-own [energy refX refY]

...
to setup
  ca
  setup-patches
  setup-agents
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches[
    let x 28
    let y 48
    if pycor mod 2 = 0
    [set x 48 set y 28] 
    ifelse pxcor mod 2 = 0 
    [set pcolor x]
    [set pcolor y]
  ]
end

to setup-agents
  create-mice N-mice
  [
    set shape "mouse side"
    set color 4
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set energy 50
    set refX 25
    set refY 25
....
to move-mice
  ask mice
  [
    let x one-of neighbors
    move-to x
    set energy energy - 1
    if energy <= 0 [die]
    ifelse show-energy?
    [set label energy set label-color black]
    [set label ""]
  ]
  end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To get assistance, you need to have a specific problem and provide the code that you are stuck on. There is nothing in this code about smell diffusing or cats etc so you haven't really got anything to work with. To get you started, have a look at the Ants model in the NetLogo Model Library - it has ants following a smell trail and the smell diffusing.

Comment: There is a keyword [diffuse]

Answer (score 1):

There is a primitive `diffuse` that does exactly that. Look it up in the truly amazing netlogo dictionary. There are several models in the model library that use it most famously the ant foraging model.

Pair that with the primitive `downhill` and your model will almost write itself.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider adding some decay to the smell. if not, there's mouse smell everywhere!
additionally some minimal awareness threshold will possibly also get your cats to pursue other leisures than teasing mice.